Bayesian Linear Regression prior question
In Bayesian Linear Regression, can the prior be used to prioritize the larger values of the w?

What exactly do you mean here? Do you want to bias the weights to be large in absolute value? If so, why?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This is the only information we were given; this is from a lecture and is one of the "intellectual discussion questions" the lecturer posed but never gave us an answer to, he wants us to basically think about it until we magically come up with an answer.  For my own general understanding and growth, since I'm not getting help from him, in a theoretical manner, is this is a typical practice?  I think the answer is probably no but I'm just looking to try to talk it out!

You're going to have to clarify your notation. Even the term weight is ambiguous
